# Is there a way to anchor vertices in a displacement modifier animation?

Tags: animation, displacement

Is there any way I can anchor specific vertices in an object in a displacement modifier? For context i am trying to animate a flag using a displacement modifier and an empty following a curve but I cant find a way to anchor the flag to the pole.[image]

Comment: Can assign a vertex group to the displace modifier.  Those verts left out wont move.  Disp texture would need to reflect somewhat being black (no disp) at pinned edge.  Recommend putting origin of flag on pinned edge as well.  Can you post more detail of you set up, ie the modifier settings and relation between flag and pole.